# How to handle Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, linq

So this happens when I try to get data from my Web Api:

ExceptionMessage:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

This is my service:

```
public async Task<ICollection<TicketDto>> GetAllUnansweredTicketsAsync()
{
        return await _context.Tickets.Include(m => m.Message)
                        .Include(u=>u.User)
                        .OrderByDescending(d=>d.Message.Date)
                        .Select(t => new TicketDto(t)).ToListAsync();
```

This is how my DTO looks like:

```
public class TicketDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public TicketDto(Ticket ticket)
    {
        ID = ticket.ID;
        Username = ticket.User.UserName;
        Issue = ticket.Message.Title;
        Date = ticket.Message.Date;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Linq to Entities* your code is executed in server side, but constructors can't be translated to *SQL* by the provider.

You can solve the problem adding an empty constructor and setting the properties:

```
...Select(t => new TicketDto
{
    ID = t.ID,
    Username = t.User.UserName,
    Issue = t.Message.Title,
    Date = t.Message.Date,
});

public class TicketDto
{
    public TicketDto()
    {
    }
    ...
```

But If you want to keep only your actual constructor you can switch to *Linq to Objects* calling `AsEnumerable()`:

```
...
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(t => new TicketDto(t))
.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot or don't want add a default contructor to the `TicketDto` class, I suggest that you materialize the query before mapping it to the DTO object :

```
public async Task<ICollection<TicketDto>> GetAllUnansweredTicketsAsync()
{
    return (await _context.Tickets.Include(m => m.Message)
        .Include(u=>u.User)
        .OrderByDescending(d=>d.Message.Date)
        .ToListAsync())
        .Select(t => new TicketDto(t))
        .ToList();
}
```

After the call to `ToListAsync` you will use [Linq to Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) rather than [Linq to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964(v=vs.100).aspx) since the collection will be materialized in memory.